# multer: Uploading Excel file to database using node.js returning undefined

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, excel, upload

I am having troubles trying to update an excel file to a database`s table. The data is being inserted into the database's table but i still getting an error Alert Fail! (object object) on the static javascript file. Maybe should I use fetch instead of ajax?

Even though I am inserting data into the database through the function, these are the errors displayed on the brownser.

```
'http://127.0.0.1:8006/api/file/upload' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
jquery.min.js:2 POST http://127.0.0.1:8006/api/file/upload net::ERR_FAILED
```

the bit of my front end code is that:

```
javascript:
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    /**
     * Upload single file to SpringBoot 
     * at RestAPI: /api/upload/file/single
     */
    $("#uploadSingleFileForm").submit(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        
        let formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        
        $.ajax({
            url : apiServer + 'file/upload',
            type : 'POST',
            data : formData,
            async : false,
            cache : false,
            contentType : false,
            enctype : 'multipart/form-data',
            processData : false,
            success : function(response) {
                $("#response").empty();
                if(response.status !== "error"){
                    let displayInfo = response.filename + " : " + response.message + "<br>"; 
                    
                    $("#response").append(displayInfo);
                    // add some css
                    $("#response").css("display", "block");
                    $("#response").css("background-color", "#e6e6ff");
                    $("#response").css("border", "solid 1px black");
                    $("#response").css("border-radius", "3px");
                    $("#response").css("margin", "10px");
                    $("#response").css("padding", "10px");
                }else{
                    $("#response").css("display", "none");
                    let error = response.error;
                    alert(error);
                }
            },
            error: function(e){
                alert("Fail! " + e);
            }
        });
        
        return false;
    });
    
    /**
     * Upload Multiple Files to SpringBoot RestAPI
     */
    $("#uploadMultipleFilesForm").submit(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        
        let formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        
        $.ajax({
            url : apiServer + 'file/multiple/upload',
            type : 'POST',
            data : formData,
            async : false,
            cache : false,
            contentType : false,
            enctype : 'multipart/form-data',
            processData : false,
            success : function(response) {              
                $("#responses").empty();    
                
                let displayInfo = "<ul>";
                
                for(let i=0; i<response.length; i++){
                    
                    displayInfo += "<li>" + response[i].filename + "&nbsp; : &nbsp;" + response[i].message;
                                    
                    displayInfo += "</li>";
                }
                $("#responses").append(displayInfo + "</ul>");
                $("#responses").css("display", "block");
                
                // add some css
                $("#responses").css("background-color", "#e6e6ff");
                $("#responses").css("border", "solid 1px black");
                $("#responses").css("border-radius", "3px");
                $("#responses").css("margin", "10px");
                $("#responses").css("padding", "10px");
            },
            error: function(e){
                alert("Fail! " + e);
            }
        });
        
        return false;
    });
})
```

that is the excel.controller.js - back-end

```
var stream = require('stream');
var await = require('await')

const db = require('./db.config.js');
const stckinvt = db.stckinvt;

const excel = require('exceljs');

const readXlsxFile = require('read-excel-file/node');

exports.uploadFile = (req, res) => {

    try{
        let filePath = __basedir + "/uploads/" + req.file.filename;

        readXlsxFile(filePath).then(rows => {
            // `rows` is an array of rows
            // each row being an array of cells.   
            console.log(rows);
    
            // Remove Header ROW
            rows.shift();
            
            const stockinventory = [];
    
            let length = rows.length;
    
            for(let i=0; i<length; i++){
    
                let stckinvt = {
                    id: rows[i][0],
                    store: rows[i][1],
                    itemNo: rows[i][2],
                    itemName: rows[i][3],
                }
    
                stockinventory.push(stckinvt);
            }
    
            stckinvt.bulkCreate(stockinventory).then(() => {
                const result = {
                    status: "ok",
                    filename: req.file.originalname,
                    message: "Upload Successfully!",
                }

                res.json(result);
            });
        });
    }catch(error){
        const result = {
            status: "fail",
            filename: req.file.originalname,
            message: "Upload Error! message = " + error.message
        }
        res.json(result);
    }
}
```

EDIT: I found out what was wrong, and it is related to the Restify Plugin API bodyParser:
If I change this line:

```
server.use([cors.actual, restify.plugins.queryParser(), restify.plugins.bodyParser()]);
```

To this:

```
server.use([cors.actual, restify.plugins.queryParser()]);
```

It works perfectly but I am afraid I can not just delete this information because can be important to other pages on the server. Any ideas?

Comment: The error means that `req.file` is undefined. You need to test for that case before trying to do something with `req.file.originalname` to avoid this error. (also, this question is a wall of code; please reduce it to strictly the relevant parts)